# Octave: read a string from a file including blanks

Tags: octave

I want to read a file that has lines of 80 character length, containing blank spaces.
I want to have the 80 characters including the blanks in one string.
I use Data=fscanf(fid,"%80s","C") but the returned string stops at the first blank character encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The anser is to use Data=fgetl(fid). This reads line by line including blanks.